# Does kmalloc() reserve Copy-On-Write (COW) mappings?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

My understanding is that `kmalloc()` allocates from anonymous memory. Does this actually reserve the physical memory immediately or is that going to happen only when a write page fault happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kmalloc()` does not usually allocate memory pages<sup>**(1)**</sup>, it's more complicated than that. `kmalloc()` is used to request memory for small objects (smaller than the page size), and manages those requests using already existing memory pages, similarly to what libc's `malloc()` does to manage the heap in userspace programs.

There are different allocators that can be used in the Linux kernel: [SLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation), [SLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLOB) and [SLUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLUB_(software)). Those use different approaches for the same goal: managing allocation and deallocation of kernel memory for small objects at runtime. A call to `kmalloc()` may use any of the three depending on which one was configured into the kernel.

A call to `kmalloc()` does not usually reserve memory at all, but rather just manages already reserved memory. Therefore memory returned by `kmalloc()` does not require a subsequent page fault like a page requested through `mmap()` normally would.

Copy on Write (CoW) is a different concept. Although it's still triggered through page faults, CoW is a mechanism used by the kernel to save space sharing existing mappings until they are modified. It is not what happens when a fault is triggered on a newly allocated memory page. A great example of CoW is what happens when the `fork` syscall is invoked: the process memory of the child process is not immediately duplicated, instead existing pages are marked as CoW, and the duplication only happens at the first attempt to write.

I believe this should clear any doubt you have. The short answer is that `kmalloc()` does not usually "reserve the physical memory immediately" because it merely allocates an object from *already reserved* memory.

<sup>(1) Unless the request is very large, in which case it falls back to actually allocating new memory through `alloc_pages()`.</sup>